# I've deleted one of the win10 drives and got error: no such partition

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I have two win10 and a Ubuntu OS in my computer. 
I decided to delete on of theme so i formatted one of the drives who contains one of my windows then i deleted it and merged the with the remaining windows drive.
now i get the `error:no such partition` and when i use command `set` it prints `prefix=(hd0,msdos9)` while i don't have `(hd0,msdos9)` in the list of printed drives using `ls` command. 
i'll be apreciated if you answer me.

Comment: Where are you seeing both messages?  It sounds like maybe GRUB wasn't updated to reflect the change.  If so, you may need to repair GRUB to bring it up to date.  See https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/ (ignore the title, it's about the GRUB repair tool).

Comment: thatnks alot! it worked.